# Find $P(Z_n \geq y)$, as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are i.i.d. standard Gaussian random variables and we define

$$Z_n : = \max_{i=1,\ldots,n} |X_i|$$

, my theory material says that as $n \rightarrow \infty$ and $y > 0$ we have

$$P(Z_n \geq y) = 1 - (1- P(|X_1| \geq y) ).$$

I try to find out why this holds.
In an old question I found $P(Z_n \geq y) = 1- (1 - P(|X_1| \geq y))^n$, but I don't know whether I can use that here since $n \rightarrow \infty$.

**Edit**:

$P(Z_n \geq y)$
$ =  P(|X_1| \geq y, \ldots , |X_n| \geq y) $
$= P(|X_1| \geq y) \cdot \ldots \cdot P(|X_n| \geq y) $
$= \Pi_{i=1} ^{n}  [1 - P(|X_i| < y) ] $
$= [1 - P(|X_1| < y) ]^n $
$= P(|X_1| \geq  y)^n$

Comment: Look at the complement event of $Z_n\geq y$: all the variables must be smaller than $y$. Use independence to deduce the second inequality you wrote.

Comment: Please check your question where you write $$P(Z_n \geq y) = 1 - (1- P(|X_1| \geq y) )$$. This is equivalent to $$P(Z_n \geq y) = P(|X_1| \geq y)$$, which is inconsistent with the rest of your questions (as well as incorrect).

Comment: @uniquesolution Which inequality? I edit the question and got $P(Z_n \geq y) = P(|X_1| \geq y)^n$. This is not equal to $1 - (1- P(|X_1| \geq y) )$.

Comment: @mlc I only ask one question, namely why the equality $P(Z_n \geq y) = 1 - (1- P(|X_1| \geq y) )$ holds.

Comment: @clubkli I got it, now (sorry). The wrong inequality was from the book and you were asking whether you had the right one. (You did, as the Answer shows.)

Answer (score 0):

The event you have is that at least one of the $X_i$ is greater than $y$. Its complement is that all $X_i$ are less than $y$. Meaning, $P(X_i < y\  \forall i)$. Since those are i.i.d. variables, the above is really $\prod_{i=1} ^n P(X_i < y)$, which is $P(X_1 < y)^n$. $P(X_1 < y)$ is less than $1$, so $P(X_1 < y)^n \to 0$ and therefore your event will happen w.p. one.